# Error when defining custom notation for an embedded logic

Tags: coq, notation

I'm working on a colleague's embedding of modal logic in Coq and I'm trying to define a custom notation for formulas of said logic, like presented [here](https://coq.discourse.group/t/use-notations-to-define-an-embedded-language-inside-coq/703/7) and also on Volume 2 of the book Software Foundations. So far I have this:

```
Declare Custom Entry modal.
Declare Scope modal_scope.

Notation "[! m !]"    := m (at level 0, m custom modal at level 99) : modal_scope.
Notation " p -> q "   := (Implies p q) (in custom modal at level 13, right associativity).

Open Scope modal_scope.

Definition test:
  [! p -> q !].
```

However, the `Definition` gives this error:

```
Syntax error: [constr:modal level 99] expected after '[!' (in [constr:operconstr]).
```

And I can't figure out why. I found some questions on SO where the suggested solution is to change the precedence of the first symbol, `p` in this case, however that just throws another error. The Coq manual wasn't very helpful either.

What is causing this error and why do the other notations work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared your own syntactic category for your logic: The parser, after `[!`, expects only things that are in the entry `modal`. `p` is an identifier, and the parser does not expect arbitrary identifiers.

In the [documentation on custom entries](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/user-extensions/syntax-extensions.html#custom-entries), you can find a hint on how to add identifiers to your entry:

```
Declare Custom Entry modal.
Declare Scope modal_scope.

Print Grammar constr.

Axiom Implies : Prop -> Prop -> Prop.

Notation "x" := x (in custom modal at level 0, x ident).

Notation "[! m !]"    := m (at level 0, m custom modal at level 99) : modal_scope.
Notation "p '->' q"   := (Implies p q) (in custom modal at level 13, right associativity).

Open Scope modal_scope.

Definition testp p q:
  [! p -> q !] .
```

> I found some questions on SO where the suggested solution is to change the precedence of the first symbol, p in this case, however that just throws another error. The Coq manual wasn't very helpful either.

This can be a solution if the left-most symbol of your notation is a terminal, not a variable.